# Transmitter adc value with UART

Tags: stm32, adc, transmitter

Can the adc value be sent to the computer at a sample rate of 48 kHz real time?
I am using STM32F103C8 and this FTDI.
[image]

Comment: The long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore it has been moved to chat and should be continued there (link below). --- As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here which try to clarify and understand the question, might be deleted without notice. **Keep it in chat, please!** When someone has got enough information from the chat to post an answer, then please do that as usual. Any updates to the question which are decided during the chat, should be made via an edit to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128749/discussion-on-question-by-jason-transmitter-adc-value-with-uart).

Answer (score 3):

Most likely yes. At least in theory, but it depends on many factors.

You have 12 bits per sample so for simplicity two bytes must be sent per sample to send the data in binary. For a sampling rate of 48000 samples per second, that's 96000 bytes per second, so in theory at least a baud rate of 960 kbps is needed.

The FTDI FT232RL is capable of up to 3 Mbps rate, so that is not the limiting factor. However it has a buffer FIFO of 256 bytes, and USB host polls the chip only every 1 millisecond in theory, so in theory, only 256 thousand bytes or 2.56 Mbps throughput is achievable even if 3 Mbps baud rate is used.

Depending on how you set up the STM32F103 clocking, it should easily reach a baud rate of 3 Mbps as well. So that is also not an issue.

In practice if the operating system is heavily loaded, it is possible that USB interface is polled with some latency, so it might limit the throughput somewhat.

The 1 Mbps rate should suffice for binary transfer. Even less is needed if you cleverly pack the data for transmission, like sending two 12-bit samples in three bytes.

You mention sending the 12-bit result as 4 characters like "4095", but that would double the bandwidth to about 2 Mbps. And that does not include any delimiter, so you would not know which four digits belong to which sample. If you delimit the samples with comma or space, that's already 5 bytes per sample, which adds up to 2.4 Mbps throughput requirement. It may not work reliably any more.

Comment: Hi @Justme
thank you for your time what is your suggestion ?

Comment: What should i do ?

Comment: @Jason What suggestion you mean? You asked a question, I answered it. What do you mean what you should do about what?